# Average Between 4 iterations using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to run a process in loop, i am already getting start time, end time and difference between them, is there a way i can average those three timers using Python.

```
timestr1 = datetime.now()
print line
print >> sys.stderr, "End Time: %s" %(timestr1)
logfile.write("End Time: "+ format(timestr1) + "\n")
logfile.write("Run Time: "+ format(timestr1-timestr) + "\n")
print ('Time ran for: {}'.format(timestr1-timestr))
```

this run's for 4 iterations is there a way i can average 4 iterations.

Comment: Sure, you can add each iteration into a tmp variable and after the 4th loop you'll divide it by 4. No ?

Comment: Temporary Variable value changes at each iteration correct.